# Why any Administration Group account Log into SP as system account?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, user-profile, administration, app, server-farm

Every time I create a new Web application and site collection and setting any "Admins group user" as SC administrator or WebApp Adminstrator , when a Log into the new site with this user I see this is logged-in as SYSTEM ACCOUNT.

I'm trying to Deploy a App for Sp 2103 but there are some troubles with it too.

If i try to deploy my solution with Visual studio,  running Vs as these users,  it returns me the error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The
>   System Account cannot perform this action.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the application pool is running under that user. If you Login to your Site with the same (managed) account the web application is running under, it will identify you as "System Account".